# Heatilator fireplace fail

Tags: fireplace

We have an old heatilator fireplace in our 1960's house.  I called a well recommended Fireplace guy to replace the rotted out damper, and he inspected the fireplace and told me (and showed me) that there is no liner in my chimney.  He said that the heatilator box is shot and the fix is an insert and stainless steel liner.  We bought our house about a year ago and used the fireplace all winter, so I do want a working fireplace. He quoted me about $4300.

My questions are this:  What is your feedback for this scenario?  Is this the proper fix for the problem?  Is there an alternate workable fix that you can think of?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Fix for which problem? The bad damper or the lack of a modern safety feature (the liner)?

Comment: Call your homeowners insurance agent as well. About 10 years ago my parents homeowners insurance paid like 80% of the chimney re-lining.  Completely shocked my parents at the time, the chimney company was who suggested asking.

Comment: Both, plus the firebox failure.  He told me that the 1950's-1960's heatilator fireplaces are failing and that mine has.    Thanks for the suggestion about insurance company.

Answer (score 1):

I would call a chimney person to inspect the chimney and make recommendations to fix the chimney. He will be able to give you pricing on your repair options for the chimney. The cost of the chimney repairs will vary depending on the type of fuel you will be using and what the codes are for your area. Where I live the cost for a chimney repair for natural gas is much less than the cost to burn a solid fuel (wood) etc. Depending upon the condition of the present insert, you could see if it can be repaired.

Comment: Thank you.  The guy who came in is a chimney person and well recommended.  I was hoping for confirmation of what he told me and any alternate ideas.

Comment: We don't have natural gas, so that is not an option.  (Don't have it in our neighborhood; we are very rural.)  This is a wood-burning fireplace.